# Keep nav items on one line on small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently my nav nav-tabs are being pushed to a next line if i make my screen smaller, however i wish to keep them on one line and enable overflow-x when they pass the 768px breakpoint.
I cannot figure out how to make this work, **can anyone help?**

*html*

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="min-width" ng-if="user.loggedIn" id="char-nav" bs-scrollspy-list>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li><a href="/#char-identity">Identity</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/#char-attributes">Attributes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/#char-skills">Skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/#char-spells">Spells</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/#char-passives">Passives</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/#char-equipment">Equipment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/#char-consumables">Consumables</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

*current css*

```
#char-nav {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 13px;
}
.nav-tabs {
    border: none;
}
.nav > li > a {
    padding: 8px 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #char-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        max-width: 80%;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're working with bootstrap - manually force your own styling over the @media bootstrap styling by using the key-word !important after your CSS declarations, otherwise bootstrap will take priority; for example: "display: inline-block !important;"

Comment: Good thing to know, but sadly it did not help in this case :c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is a bit of css** :

```
.min-width{ 
    overflow-x:auto 
}
ul.nav{
    display:inline-flex
}
```

**And a bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/BRqVaRNnZP